# How many sigops are in the invalid block 783426?

Tags: bitcoin-core, block, block-validity, signature-operations

On April 1st 2023 F2Pool mined block 00000000000000000002ec935e245f8ae70fc68cc828f05bf4cfa002668599e4 ([full block](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5447129.msg62015952#msg62015952)) which my node failed with `bad-blk-sigops`.

Bitcoin Core stops counting as soon as it reaches the 80,000 limit.

I had a hard time counting this, but how many sigops did this block contain?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is 80,003. I arrived at the same number as Sjors by writing [a script](https://gist.github.com/vostrnad/ce761880282d881dacb5337af7d73e35) that goes through every transaction in a block and counts the sigops.

Here is a detailed breakdown:

- Bare multisig outputs: 71,200. There are 890 and each contributes 80 sigops.
- P2PKH outputs: 3320. There are 830 and each contributes 4 sigops.
- P2WPKH-in-P2SH inputs: 2219. Each contributes a single sigop.
- P2WPKH inputs: 1751. Each contributes a single sigop.
- P2WSH inputs: 1160.

  - 28 inputs contribute a single sigop.
  - 363 inputs contribute 2 sigops.
  - 128 inputs contribute 3 sigops.
  - 2 inputs contribute 4 sigops.
  - 2 inputs contribute 7 sigops.
- P2WSH-in-P2SH inputs: 193.

  - 12 inputs contribute a single sigop.
  - 29 inputs contribute 2 sigops.
  - 33 inputs contribute 3 sigops.
  - 6 inputs contribute 4 sigops.
- P2SH inputs: 160.

  - 1 input contributes 4 sigops.
  - 13 inputs contribute 12 sigops.

Comment: Can you share the script? Either in your answer or via a Github gist?

Comment: It's a "script" in a sense that it's a JavaScript (actually TypeScript) file sitting in a larger project of mine using some of its internals as dependencies. If you'd like I can produce a minimal standalone repo.

Comment: Even without the dependencies it could be useful to see the script and the queries it makes, so I can compare with what I was doing.

Comment: Here you go: https://gist.github.com/vostrnad/ce761880282d881dacb5337af7d73e35

Answer (score 6):

The correct, but non gratifying, answer is 80,003.

I found it by changing `MAX_BLOCK_SIGOPS_COST`, recompiling and the using the `invalidateblock` and `reconsiderblock` RPC to recheck it.

The block fails validation with the sigops limit set to 80,002 as passes validation when it's set to 80,003.

Comment: Was this an april fools joke by them? Is there any context as to why this occurred?

Comment: They probably miscounted the sigops on bare multisig transactions.

Comment: @Poseidon that would be a $150K prank, and they already had a different April Fools joke on social media. So I think it was an accident. I suspect they use custom software to compose the block, not Bitcoin Core's `getblocktemplate`. See also: https://twitter.com/provoost/status/1642182022176161795

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do a partial count, but I'm having a hard time counting it for P2SH and SegWit transactions.

Parse the block and store result:

```
bitcoin-cli getblock 00000000000000000002ec935e245f8ae70fc68cc828f05bf4cfa002668599e4 2 > block.json
```

This lists transactions like so:

```json
    {
      "txid": "914b24cf50f4bc930c3a11123411031010f010563ed293f65f1ef8cb9bc1e950",
      ...
      "vin": [
        {
          "txid": "cf3349976fedfe34502333310f753d91c16dccb3220d37d5f4c1a11b70eceda2",
          "vout": 1,
          "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "30440220253e9a3fc9cbae7833abc38ea29ae4f7672cb33591c227446c71b26a8199760a022071042cde824b3cfddc51888d49ac8f85062921e1430ee85885252e1a6758fc17[ALL] 02b704c5bac9ed2e23193f28f0a9e1108ff6164e713552fca936c9447566df1d66",
            "hex": "..."
          },
          "sequence": 4294967295
        }
      ],
      "vout": [
        {
          "value": 0.00071520,
          "n": 1,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 8342c5f824ae0806236e746b951e68192c1b124f OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",

            "address": "1Cy3Wd2pArq359z9d3VYMUoBQBM1kkANCn",
            "type": "pubkeyhash"
          }
        }
      ]
```

I can use `jq`, `grep`, `sed,` awk`and`wc -l` to count various stuff.

*Legacy OP_CHECKSIG:*

```
cat block.json | jq -r '.tx[].vout[].scriptPubKey.asm' | grep OP_CHECKSIG | wc -l
830
```

Each `OP_CHECKSIG` used to count as 1 sigop before SegWit, and now counts as 4.

This yields 830 * 4 = 3,320 sigops

*Bare multisig:*

```
cat block.json | jq -r '.tx[].vout[].scriptPubKey.asm' | grep OP_CHECKMULTISIG | wc -l
890
```

Each `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` counted as 20 sigops before SegWit, regardless of the number of public keys.

This yields 890 * 20 * 4 = 71,200 sigops.

*P2SH:*

Now it gets a bit more complicated. Because the P2SH script is only revealed when you *spend* it, we have to look at `scriptSig` on the inputs. Specifically we're looking for a `scriptSig` that's *not* one of these:

1. A regular `OP_CHECKSIG` spend, which always starts with a DER encoded signature (`^304.*\[.*`) and ends with a pubkey (`0.*$`).
2. P2SH wrapped v0 SegWit: `^0014.*`

We also assume it contains at least one signature, which we recognise by the presence of a sighash marker like `[ALL]`. The script itself is the last thing pushed on the stack, which is what the `awk` command gives us. We then pipe that into `decodescript`.

```
cat block.json | jq -r '.tx[].vin[].scriptSig.asm'| grep . | grep -v "^304.*\[.* 0.*$" | grep -v "^0014.*" | grep "\[" | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}' | xargs -i -n 1 bitcoin-cli decodescript {} | jq '.asm'
```

The result is a very short list consisting of 13 2-of-3 multisig transactions and 1 OP_CHECKSIG.

So that yields (13 * 3 + 1) * 4 = 160 sigops

*Pay to witness public key hash:*

For this we look at the `txinwitness` field. Specifically we check if the last stack entry is a public key.

```
cat block.json | jq -r '.tx[].vin[].txinwitness[-1]' | grep . | grep -v null | grep "^0..*" | wc -l
3981
```

This yields 3,981 sigops. *Update: Vojtěch found 2219 + 1751 = 3,970 in [his answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/117837/how-many-sigops-are-in-the-invalid-block-783426/117842#117842)*

*Pay to witness script hash:*

We again look at the last item on the witness stack, which we assume to be the script. We do the opposite of P2WPK and drop all matches with a public key. We also drop (taproot) Schnorr signatures which are 64 bytes plus optionally 1 for the SIGHASH. We also drop entries that start with 33 bytes (I think these are Tapleaf script hashes).

```
cat block.json | jq -r '.tx[].vin[].txinwitness[-1]' | grep . | grep -v null | grep -v "^0..*" | sed -r '/^.{128,130}$/d' | sed -r '/^.{66}$/d' | xargs -i -n 1 bitcoin-cli decodescript {} | jq '.asm' | grep -o "OP_CHECKSIG" | wc -l
231
```

This yields 231 sigops.

We count multisig in a similar way. First we sort them by N and not which N's are used:

```
| jq -r '.tx[].vin[].txinwitness[-1]' | grep . | grep -v null | grep -v "^03.*" | sed -r '/^.{128,130}$/d' | sed -r '/^.{66}$/d' | xargs -i -n 1 bitcoin-cli decodescript {} | jq '.asm' | grep "OP_CHECKMULTISIG" | rev | sort | rev
```

Then count the number of occurrences:

1. 2 times m-of-7: 2 * 7 = 14 sigops
2. 1 time m-of-4: 4 sigops
3. 102 times m-of-3: 306 sigops
4. 385 times m-of-2: 770 sigops
5. List item
6. 27 times 1-of-1: 27 sigops

So that yields 1,159 sigops.

**Total**

3320 + 71200 + 160 + 3981 + 231 + 1159 = **80,051**